# Why is garbage being printed for the first element in this array?

Tags: c, string

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include<string.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>

  int main()
  {
     char *words[] = {"mHello", "kWorld", "kHow", "9Are", "3You?"};
     char **parsed = malloc(5);
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
        int n = strlen(words[i]);
        parsed[i] = malloc(n);
        strncpy(parsed[i], words[i] + 1, n);
        printf("[%s] ", parsed[i]); 
     }
     printf("\n----------------------\n");
     for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       printf("[%s] ", parsed[i]);
         return 0;
  }
```

`parsed[i]` contains `words[i]` without the first character.

The output is

```
 [Hello] [World] [How] [Are] [You?]
 ----------------------
 [▒▒ o] [World] [How] [Are] [You?]
```

Why does the first printf call to `parsed[0]` work correctly while the second one doesn't ?

Also, if I remove one element from `words`, this code works correct. What is going on ?

Comment: Ouch, you are right. I just saw it and thus deleted my comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `malloc` is not allocating the correct space for pointers to strings though, it should be

```
parsed = malloc(sizeof(char*)*5)
```

Comment: I wish C had a straight forward way of failing. Its hard for me to debug when the code works randomly like this.

Comment: @user1033777 If you tried to `free` your `parsed[i]`, you'd probably get a nice informative segfault when trying to free `parsed[0]` because the further `malloc`s probably clobber the bookkeeping data for that. Also, valgrind helps.

Comment: Yup, `free` does result in one. I'll check out valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, `**parsed` is not big enough for all the pointers being stored there. It should be allocated

```
parsed=malloc(sizeof(*parsed)*5);
```

And you could roll the individual string allocation and copy all into one like this:

```
parsed[i]=strdup(words[i]+1);
```

This also handles string length correctly, now at first sight it looks like there could have been an off by one issue.

Comment: Wouldn't this be _too_ much memory?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Why? It is exactly the correct amount - 5 times the size of a pointer.

Comment: I always use the idiom x=malloc(sizeof(*x)*n), it works no matter what type of pointer x is.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, you can track down memory erros like these using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

An alternative tool if you want your code to fail hard in these cases is [address sanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizerAlgorithm).